# Why create a separate application for RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest, yii2

In the guide for Yii 2 it is said:

> While not required, it is recommended that you develop your RESTful
>   APIs as a separate application, different from your Web front end and
>   back end for easier maintenance.

Source: [RESTful Web Services - Quick Start](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#summary)

What does this mean? Would this be a completely different application or can it be in the same folder as the 'normal' web application? I've just started with my application so I can change things easily, more or less. But I'm wondering: if I would create another application than my business logic would not be accessible.

Why and how I should create another application? And when it's not required?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means you have to create an application like frontend or backend(**Yii 2 advanced application template**), 
what you have to do is create another directory call 'api' same as backend or frontend, and it'll contain folder structure same as backend|frontend except assets, views, widgets etc.

Basically you need folder structure like this

```
api

-config
-modules
--v1
---controllers
---models
-runtime
-tests
-web

backend
common
console
environments
frontend
```

---

If you'r going to use **Yii 2 basic application template** to develop rest api, it's posible. create module call 'api' and create a sub directory call 'v1' as sub-module. 
[(Yii doc -A module may consist of sub-modules.)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html)[(GiovanniDerks - backend sub-modules)](http://www.slideshare.net/GiovanniDerks/yii-backend-submodules-28238101)

```
-modules
--api
---v1
----controllers
----models
```

There is an advantage of using one of these folder structure, because you don't have to worry about route much.

```
https://domain.com/api/v1/products
```

Here is good example for RESTful API with advance template

[Setup RESTful API in Yii2(budiirawan)](https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api)

API & RESTFull API are different. RESTFull APIs have to have REST standards. basically that's why APIs are developed as separate application. in normal app, we create 4 actions for CRUD functions. but in yii2 RESTFull API we just create One action for all CRUD functions. (Controllers extend from REST Active Controller - yii\rest\ActiveController ). in core code you can find find 4 actions for different headers GET,POST,PUT & DELETE .

```
'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
'create' => ['POST'],
'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
'delete' => ['DELETE'],
```

for authentication basically we can use 'HTTP Basic Authentication'

Comment: This is already quite helpful. Thanks. And I think the answer to 'Why' is that the API has not much in common with other applications. The business logic is moved to the user of the api, that is, it could be contained in JavaScript logic.

Comment: API & RESTFull API are different. RESTFull APIs have to have REST standards. basically that's why APIs are developed as separate application. in normal app, we create 4 actions for CRUD functions. but in yii2 RESTFull API we just create One action for all CRUD functions. (Controllers extend from REST Active Controller -  yii\rest\ActiveController ). in core code you can find find 4 actions for different headers GET,POST,PUT & DELETE ('index,view' => ['GET','HEAD'],'create' => ['POST'], 'update' => ['PUT','PATCH'],'delete' => ['DELETE']). for authentication basically use 'basic authentication'

Comment: Hi rocsch, this part is not clear to me "The business logic is moved to the user of the api, that is, it could be contained in JavaScript logic."

Comment: My understand is now that if you have RESTful API then you do things different compared to a normal web application. In the Yii Guide it is said: RESTful is all about resources. Okay. And what can we do with resources? Just GET, POST, DELETE and so on. Primitive actions. But somewhere you may want to have something like convertIt(), for example. A more complex action. In my opinion this is business logic. And this, as the user of a RESTful API, could be part of some JavaScript code. convertIt() does the required calls against the rest api to achieve its goal. Does this make sense?

Comment: Agreed, But some case like sending email functionality for password reset or user registration though it's not resources, we have to use customize actions with REST standards.   
definitely we can use JavaScript language(AngularJs) to build business logic in client side applications.(Ex: in backend & frontend in Yii2 Advance template). AngularJs is ideal with APIs i guess. 

[link](http://precious.hu/b/Oreilly.REST.API.Design.Rulebook.Oct.2011.pdf)

Comment: Interesting that you mention this. Because 'password reset' could be part of the 'normal' web application already. But with the advice to build another application for the RESTful API it sounds like you have to double this functionality. Or would then e.g. the AngularJS logic use both APIs? I assumed if I would build an AngularJS client I would solely use the RESTful API, but that might be wrong or even not possible... Not sure.

Comment: yes, we have to double this functionality to optimize our operations. as i know, API's provide resources for 3rd party clients to use or build applications with our resources. but in our own app(backend & frontend) we don't have to use API for that. we can build complex business logic with optimized way(Ex: we can get whole list of objects with many relational data, but in APIs we don't do that, maximum we would use one level depth like /api/v1/user/123/friends NOT /api/v1/user/123/friends/456/frineds). if we choose Yii 2 advance template. we can use AngularJs for frontend even backend.

Comment: Hi all, I think this might also help someone. https://github.com/choxx/yii2-advanced-improved-template-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

This article explain the idea and the why , also it provide you a starter project called "yii2-advanced-api": http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

Comment: Thanks. Chanuka has already posted the link to the corresponding github project.

Comment: This might also help. https://github.com/choxx/yii2-advanced-improved-template-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

IMHO if you need REST API for Angular.js or Knockout.js AJAX calls on your website it's an overhead to do it as a separate application. Because you  will have issues with cross-domain AJAX calls (especially for POST requests).

I think it's enough to make a module (API) in the frontend for REST API