# How to call API from frontend/backend application in Yii?

Tags: php, api, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So Yii structure is like this.

```
api
  |modules
     |v2
         |actions
common
frontend
backend
```

We can call common in backend and frontend. Also we are able to call backend modules in frontend module.

Is it possible to call API i.e v2 action from frontend module in yii?

This is required to be done as API module is already there. And so for avoiding backend logic we need to call API.

Comment: you can refer this link : http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230517/why-create-a-separate-application-for-restful-api

Comment: @NikunjRathod: That's not related.

Comment: You Can. Using proper namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SOA(Service oriented Architecture) in the Yii, for this you have to create the services folder in that service write your logics that can be used by your backend and API's both so your frontend will be API based and backend will be service based. Like as below

api 

    |modules

        |v2

             |actions

common
frontend
backend
**services**